# how can i make onclick to all the elments?

Tags: javascript, onclick

i try to make onclick event to all the decomnt that give me back the elment id that i click on .

thank you

i tried to you the parent id 
document.getElementById("parent").onclick = function(){btnIsClicked(this.id)};

this work but give me the parent id not the clicked one..

```
document.getElementById(*).onclick = function(){btnIsClicked(this.id)};

function btnIsClicked(id){
  console.log(id);
}
```

please i need some thing like * to make it for all but in same time give me the id of the clicked elment (not the just the parent one)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the event listener to the `document` and access the element that was clicked as `event.target`

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.id);
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box3" class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for achive this.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('*');
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const element = elements[i];
  element.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    btnIsClicked(e.target.id);
  });
}

function btnIsClicked(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#element-one {
  background: blue;
}

#element-two {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="element-one"></div>
<div id="element-two"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener to the document body.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = function(e) {console.log(e.target.id)};
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach using querySelectorAll and stopPropagation() to get the exact element clicked.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("*")].forEach(em => {
  em.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.target)
  })
});
```

```html
<h1>title</h1>
<div>text inside div
<span>text inside span</span>
</div>
```